# Only 32 out of 90 legends showing up on screen on a plot created using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Basically I am creating a PCA scatter plot.  I have 90 different populations.  Each population is represented by a different shape.  Creating the scatter plot seems easy, however all my legends are not showing up on the screen.  The basic formula I use is

```
qplot(data=dat, x=dat[,1], y=dat=[1[, color= factor (dat[,11]), 
      shape= factor(dat[,11])) + scale_shape_manual(values=27:132)
```

The formula works for smaller populations.  However, how do I make legends smaller and fit into a screen?

Comment: Do I understand correctly you're expecting your reader to discern 90 different shapes on your plot?

Comment: Each shape+ color combo is associated with a legend on the right.  However legend not fitting on screen. Only 32 out of 90 showing up.

Comment: I think you need to rethink of what you're trying to bring across.

Comment: Well, let's say I want just 50 legends to show on screen instead of 90.  Is it possible to change texts, space between rows, etc in the legend?  I need more than 32 at least.

Comment: Note that as few as 21 legend items is enough to get you onto JunkCharts: http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2013/04/bad-charts-can-happen-to-good-people.html

Comment: Can you upload `dat` somewhere and post a link to it?

Comment: This question has no example data, no runnable code, and it is ill-posed (i.e. plotting 90 categories needs to be avoided using clustering or other dimensional reduction). So I am wondering why all the interest and upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using `latticeExtra` ( to get `ggplot2` like theme) but good luck to discern **90 colors**:) ( I would try some rCharts intercative plots)

[image]

```
library(directlabels)
set.seed(1)
n = 1000
N = 90
dat = data.frame(x=runif(n,1,10),
                 y=runif(n,1,10),
                 col=paste0('pop',gl(N,n/N)))
library(latticeExtra)
xyplot(y~x,data=dat,groups=col,
       auto.key=list(columns=10),
       par.settings = ggplot2like(), axis = axis.grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the comments above, have you tried some large number of rows and put the legend at the bottom?  For example

guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 25))